# Does (forced) measurment of one subsystem decreases entanglement entropy?

Tags: entropy, quantum-measurements

## Problem

Perhaps this is simple question, but I failed to find the mathematical proof.

Suppose there is a tripartite pure state $\rho_{ABC}$ (A,B,C are non-overlapping). The von Neumann entanglement entropy is denoted as $S_A(\rho_{ABC})$, which is equal to $S_{BC}( \rho_{ABC} )$ as it  is a pure state.

Now we make a measurement on C, and post-select the outcome to be $|C \rangle$. Mathematically it means to project the density matrix $\rho_{ABC}$
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{AB} = \frac{\Pi_C \rho_{ABC} \Pi_C}{\text{tr}(\Pi_C \rho_{ABC} \Pi_C)}, \quad \text{where } \Pi_C = | C \rangle \langle C|
\end{equation}
assuming $\text{tr}(\Pi_C \rho_{ABC} \Pi_C) \ne 0$ (in the real problem this is gaurenteed).

My question is: does the entanglement in $A$ decrease? In other words, is the following true
\begin{equation}
S_A( \sigma_{AB} ) \le S_A( \rho_{ABC} ) 
\end{equation}

## Intuition

Suppose $C$ is independent from $AB$, then $\rho_{ABC} = \rho_{AB} \otimes \rho_C$. After the measurement $\sigma_{AB} = \rho_{AB}$, we have $A( \sigma_{AB} ) \le S_A( \rho_{ABC} )$.

If $B$ is empty, then the measurement completely destroys the entanglement.
$S_A( \rho'_{AB} ) = 0$, the inequality holds trivially.

More generally, I expect the measurement in $C$ reduces the uncertainty in region $A$, and so the entanglement entropy should decrease. But I do not know how to show it mathematically.

## Attempt

If the measurement is a projective measurement without post-selection, then the resulting density matrix can be written as $\Phi(\rho_ABC) = \sum_i \Pi_i \rho_{ABC} \Pi_i$, where $\Pi_i$ forms a complete set of projectors on C and $\Phi$ denotes this quantum channel.

Via strong subadditivity (or monotonicity of relative entropy), the mutual information decreases after applying a quantum channel
\begin{equation}
I_{A;BC}(\rho_{ABC} ) \ge I_{A;B} ( \Phi(\rho_ABC) )
\end{equation}
The LHS is $2 S_A( \rho_{ABC} )$, but the RHS is not $2 S_A( \Phi(\rho_ABC) )$ since $\Phi(\rho_ABC)$ is not a pure state. Not sure if it helps.

The measurement leading to $\sigma_{AB}$ has a forced result and so is a non-linear operation, rather than a quantum channel. Results of monotonicity regarding quantum channels do not apply.

I feel this problem might very likely have been solved in the literature.
Please point me to the relevant references or share your thoughts.

Thank you!